# Webpack doesn't find any of the Angular 2 modules

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to migrate simple Angular 2 app written in Typescript 2 from Browserify to Webpack 2 but getting error about angular modules not found and browser field. After looking into several sample projects and tutorials I still don't know what could be the problem. It builds nicely with Browserify and Tsify.

```
ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/platform-browser-dynamic' in '/opt/project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
resolve './src/platform-browser-dynamic' in '/opt/project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
  using description file: /opt/project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /opt/project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/package.json (relative path: .)
    using description file: /opt/project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/package.json (relative path: ./src/platform-browser-dynamic)
      as directory
        /opt/project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform-browser-dynamic doesn't exist
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /opt/project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform-browser-dynamic doesn't exist
      js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /opt/project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform-browser-dynamicjs doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /opt/project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform-browser-dynamic.ts doesn't exist
[/opt/project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform-browser-dynamic]
[/opt/project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform-browser-dynamic]
[/opt/project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform-browser-dynamicjs]
[/opt/project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform-browser-dynamic.ts]
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js 13:0-47
 @ ./src/main.ts
...and so on...
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './src/main.ts',
    },
    output: {
        path: './build',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['js', '.ts'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: ['ts-loader'],
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: The `js` extension in `resolve.extensions` should be `.js`. I'm not sure if that is the answer, but it should be changed.

Comment: Did you get a satisfactory answer to this? my webpack config looks like yours by chance. Whats in your tsconfig.json?

Comment: If I remember correctly then Paus S comment helped me. Later I migrated to ES6.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a really simple app and your going to update anyway, you could update to use the [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli). It's the recommended approach to use angular2 and as long as your using the latest version it uses webpack.